# How can I input text from a web page and apply Javascript function to text and output it?

Tags: javascript, html

**Hello everybody**, 
I'll try being more specific this time.
 I am building a web page in which the user will be able to write some text,and then after applying the below function to it,I would like to output the result so that the user can see it.

```
     function convert1 (word)
{
    var ret = "",
        temp = "",
        tmp = "",
        keep = 0,
        check = 0;

    for (var i = 0;i < 1; i++)
    {
            if (word[0] == "l")
            {
                ret += "l";
            }else if (word[0] == "a" || word[0] == "e" || word[0] == "i" || word[0] == "o" || word[0] == "u")
            {
                ret += "l";
                ret += word[0];
            }else
            {
                ret += "l";
                temp += word[0];
            }
    }
    for (var j = 1; j < word.length; j++)
    {
             if (word[0] == "a" || word[0] == "e" || word[0] == "i" || word[0] == "o" || word[0] == "u")
             {
                if (word[j] == "a" || word[j] == "e" || word[j] == "i" || word[j] == "o" || word[j] == "u" || word[j] == "'" || word[j] == "-")
                {
                    ret += word[j];
                }else
                {
                    keep++;
                    if (keep == 1)
                    {
                        temp = word[j];
                        ret += "l";
                    }else
                    {
                    ret += word[j];
                    }
                }
             }else if (word[0] == "l")
             {
                if (word[j] == "a" || word[j] == "e" || word[j] == "i" || word[j] == "o" || word[j] == "u" || word[j] == "'" || word[j] == "-")
                {
                    ret += word[j];
                }else
                {
                 keep++;
                    if (keep == 1)
                    {
                        temp += word[j];
                        ret += "l";
                    }else 
                    {
                        ret += word[j];
                    }
                }
             }else
             {
                ret += word[j];
             }
    }   
    ret += temp;
    for (var k = 1;k < ret.length; k++){
        if (ret[k] == "a" || ret[k] == "e" || ret[k] == "i" || ret[k] == "o" || ret[k] == "u" || ret[k] == "'" || ret[k] == "-")
        {}else{
            check += 1;
        } 
    }
    if (check > 0)
    {
        ret += "i";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why this:

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<button type="button" onclick="encrypt()"/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function encrypt() {
    var text = document.getElementById('input');

    var encrypted = convert1(text);

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = encrypted;
}
```

isn't working,and how to make it work?

Comment: Questions asking for external resources are likely to be flagged as off-topic, just warning you. P.S. Sorry, don't know much about en-/de-cryption.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide your own function, but it would be like this:

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<button type="button" onclick="encrypt()"/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function encrypt() {
    var text = document.getElementById('input');

    var encrypted = yourEncryptFunction(text);

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = encrypted;
}
```

Comment: that should apply even if my function returns something?

Comment: Your encryption function should return the encrypted string.